# Creating dummy matrix from vector NOT in data frame

Tags: r

I'm working on a problem where I have 100+ items, and the result of the problem contains those 100+ items organized in groups of 2 `n` times. I want to create an n x 100 dummy matrix for the result dataset which indicates whether or not the item was in the specific "run". I can usually easily do this with `model.matrix`, however my results sometimes don't have every item in the dataframe, and I want these to be all 0's. Example:

```
library(dplyr)
AllIDs <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H')

resultID <- c('D', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'H')
resultRun <- (rep(1:3, each = 2))
resultDF <- data.frame(resultRun, resultID, stringsAsFactors = F)

modelMat <- model.matrix(~resultDF$resultID)

dummyDF <- resultDF %>% 
  # group_by(resultRun) %>% 
  mutate(A = ifelse(resultID == 'A', 1, 0),
         B = ifelse(resultID == 'B', 1, 0),
         C = ifelse(resultID == 'C', 1, 0),
         D = ifelse(resultID == 'D', 1, 0),
         E = ifelse(resultID == 'E', 1, 0),
         G = ifelse(resultID == 'G', 1, 0),
         H = ifelse(resultID == 'H', 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(resultRun) %>% 
  summarise(A = sum(A),
            B = sum(B),
            C = sum(C),
            D = sum(D),
            E = sum(E),
            G = sum(G),
            H = sum(H))
```

Notice that even if I cleaned the intercept of `modelMat` to be the dummy vector for `A`, it's still missing `B` since `B` isn't in the results. `dummyDF` is exactly how I want it to look, but the process is way too cumbersome. My actual problem has 100+ "IDs", and they are often changing every minute. I can't be constantly updating the piping to include the different items.

I'd like to use a function that returns `dummyDF` with dummy vectors for every input in `AllIDs`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this easily by converting the 'resultID' column to `factor` with `levels` specified and then get the `table`

```
resultDF$resultID <- factor(resultID, levels = LETTERS[1:8])
cbind(resultRunn = unique(resultDF$resultRun), as.data.frame.matrix(+(table(resultDF)!=0)))
#  resultRunn A B C D E F G H
#1          1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
#2          2 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
#3          3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! I've never seen notation such as `(+(table(resultDF)!=0))`, could you walk me through what it's doing there? for example, just doing `table(resultDF)` seems to get me what I'm looking for. `?+` doesn't seem to work in the console

Comment: @CoolGuyHasChillDay  In your dataset even `table(resultDF)` would work fine.  But, I was thinking that if there are duplicates, then it would sum up.  So, I converted it to logical matrix with `!=0`.  Then coerced it to binary with `+(`